# Cannot find ".ssh" Folder on Mac

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I am trying to build up a `connection` to Amazon EC2 via SSH.
Sadly I cannot find the folder to put my `.pem` file in.

When typing

```
~/.ssh
```

In the terminal I get:

> No such file or directory

I have already tried to set up a key to create the folder:

```
sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Still cannot find it.

I am really a beginner and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Then create the folder like so: `mkdir ~/.ssh`. If you never used ssh before it won't exist.

Answer (score 4):

A `.` file is a hidden file (or folder) on a Mac.  You'll have to turn on hidden files by entering this is the terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

Edit:  I just realized you are attempting to find it from the terminal, which is not affected by the visibility.  So, if you can't find it, it's not there. It'll have to be created.

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
```